# printf in different forms

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double

I have a data type of `double`, I want to `printf` the double in the following form:

- If `double x=2` or `x=2.0` print `2` to the screen, which means if I get an integer I print an integer.
- If `double x=2.3` or `x=2.30` or any other non-whole number I print `2.3` to the screen.

Is there any way to do it shortly? or do I need to use if statements or something like that?

```
double x = 2;
printf("%d", x);
double x = 2.3;
printf("%.1f", x);
```

This is an illustration only.
I want to `printf` an integer or a double based on the value I get.

Comment: Maybe investigate the `%g` format specifier?

Comment: `%d` is always wrong to print a `double` value, doesn't matter if it holds an integral value or not.

Comment: Otherwise, that might not be very easy. Suppose, due to the inexactness of floating point values, `2.3` is stored as `2.29999999`? How will you know how many decimals to print? Please see [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: operout, If the `double` had the value of `2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`, what output would you want to see?  "2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875" or "2.3"?   This may be useful [Function to print a double - exactly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** OP wants one decimal place after the `.` when the value of not a whole number:

Use `".*"` and `trunc()` to control number of precision digits.

`trunc()` returns the `double` with the fractional part truncated.

```
double f = 2.3;
printf("%.*f\n", f != trunc(f), f);  // 1 digit
f = 2.0;
printf("%.*f\n", f != trunc(f), f);   // 0 digits, no .
```

Output

```
2.3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The *quick and dirty* way to print a `double` with a minimal number of decimals without an extra loop is to use the `%g` conversion specifier.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print_num(double x) {
     printf("%g", x);
}
```

Very small and very large values may require a more explicit approach to avoid the exponent form:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_num(double x) {
    char buf[500];
    int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.15f", x);
    while (n > 0 && buf[n - 1] == '0') {
        buf[--n] = '\0';
    }
    if (n > 0 && buf[n - 1] == '.') {
        buf[--n] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider `i` is an `int` variable. Assign value of `x` into the `i` before check like `i==x`. It will  be assigned **truncate value of x**. then

```
if(i==x) printf("%d",i);
```

**i==x** will be only true when x won't have any fragment.

```
else printf("%.1f",x);
```

Comment: This fails when the floating-point value to be converted overflows `int`. There are truncation functions for floating-point types, so there is no need to involve integer types. Also, conversion to integer does not take the floor; it truncates.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you very much for your kind information.